# Python Instagram ImportError: No module named 'bind'

Tags: python, import, instagram, importerror

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

api = InstagramAPI(client_id='########', client_secret='######')
popular_media = api.media_popular(count=20)
for media in popular_media:
    print (media.images['standard_resolution'].url)
```

ive hidden cliend_id here as well as client_secret.
when i run it i get the following error:

```
(insta1)pk@pk-900X3C-900X3D-900X4C-900X4D:~/Work/insta1$ python3 project1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
  File "/home/pk/Work/insta1/lib/python3.3/site-packages/instagram/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bind import InstagramAPIError, InstagramClientError
ImportError: No module named 'bind'
```

actually the module named bind.py is inside the instagram folder mentioned in the path so i don't understand what is wrong here.

The system is kUbuntu and python v is 3.3 as you can see from the error log.
I am running my code in virtualenv with virtualenv 'insta1' set up but there is the same error when i try to run this kind of code without virtualenv.

I am new to python and am already struggling with this issue for 2 days already. please help.

Comment: try to run `python` console and import instagram or bind and see what happens.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think this module supports Python 3? It seems to be doing implicit relative imports, which don't work anymore.

Comment: same thing: (insta1)pk@pk-900X3C-900X3D-900X4C-900X4D:~/Work/insta1$ python3
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Oct  9 2013, 14:56:03) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import instagram
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pk/Work/insta1/lib/python3.3/site-packages/instagram/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bind import InstagramAPIError, InstagramClientError
ImportError: No module named 'bind'

Comment: >>> import bind
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'bind'
>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Instagram client library does not support Python 3.

You can try to repair that imports by substituting `from bind import ...` with `from .bind import ...` in `instagram/__init__.py` and other files, but then you will probably have other problems.

But if you fix them and upload to Github, that would be great :)

Comment: This seems to be the problem but what is the python version which works ok with python-instagram? I have started to fix the problem but i cant understand how to fix issues like "import oauth2" in the client.py file. this seems broken as python3 does not see the oauth2 module. How should i correct such kind of string?

Comment: oauth2.py is just another file in the instagram module. You can import it by `from . import oauth2` (or `from instagram import oauth2` if you are outside the module).